# beforeSend, error return from php page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax with beforesend, but if an error occurs on page data.php, with feedback, "erro1" prostrate an alert warning that rushed to a user error in this request.

I would be very grateful for the help.

Code.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'data.php',
  data: 'add=1',
  beforeSend: function() {
    parent.animate({'backgroundColor': '#FFFFFF'},300);
  },
  success: function() {
 LoadingOFF();
    parent.fadeOut(300,function() {
      parent.remove();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle an error case (a 500 HTTP status, for example), use the error callback to `$.ajax`.  You can see one example of alerting the response text shown below.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'data.php',
  data: {add:1},
  beforeSend: function() {
    parent.animate({'backgroundColor': '#FFFFFF'},300);
  },
  success: function() {
    LoadingOFF();
    parent.fadeOut(300,function() {
      parent.remove();
    });
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
    if(textStatus === "timeout") {
       // handle a timeout
    } else if(textStatus === "error") {
       var httpStatus = jqXHR.status // would be 500 for an error
       var responseText = jqXHR.responseText;
       alert(responseText);
    }
    // turn loading off, etc. as needed
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

data should be in key value pair

```
{add: "1"};
```

Comment: Thanks, how do you know if you receive an alert message "erro1" data.php the page?

Comment: Thanks, How do I do  , if an error occurs on the page data.php ,select, show an alert to a user's page.

Comment: use echo on data.php and see in firebug console, better u also use `dataType : 'json'` and u can use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` of php